# Display Hidden Content when JavaScript is Disabled

Tags: fancybox, hidden, javascript

I have a chunk of content in HTML that is viewable when JavaScript is enabled with fancyBox.  The read more link, when clicked, triggers fancyBox to pop up a window that shows the hidden content.  The Intro, More and Bob parts are displayed in the fancyBox, but the Intro and Bob parts are displayed first, before the read more linked is clicked.  It's a testimonial list, with the read more sections appearing with fancyBox.

```
...
<li>

    <!-- hidden div begin-->
    <div id="read-more-1" style="display: none;">
        <p>Intro More</p>
        <span class="source">Bob</span>
    </div>
    <!-- hidden div end-->

    <!-- displayed begin-->
    <p>Intro</p>
    <a class="fancy-monials" href="#read-more-1">Read more...</a><br />
    <span class="source">Bob</span>
    <!-- displayed begin-->

</li>
...
```

If I disable JavaScript and click the read more link, it just takes me to my home page.  Which I expect.

I've flirted with building a `<noscript>` block that re-displays the testimonials in full, and hides the others but that seems tedious and hacky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One common way to solve this type of problem is to add a `class="no-js"` attribute to your page's `html` element, and then remove this class using javascript.

You can then use this class as a styling hook in your CSS to show/hide content depending on whether JS is enabled. So at the most basic, you might do this (using your code from above):

```
<html class="no-js">
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            var dde = document.documentElement;
            dde.className = dde.className.replace('no-js','js');
        </script>
        <style type="text/css">
            .no-js .read-more {
                display: block;
            }
            .js .read-more {
                display: none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- ... -->
        <ul>
            <li>
                <!-- hidden div begin-->
                <div id="read-more-1" class="read-more">
                    <p>Intro More</p>
                    <span class="source">Bob</span>
                </div>
                <!-- hidden div end-->

                <!-- displayed begin-->
                <p>Intro</p>
                <a class="fancy-monials" href="#read-more-1">Read more...</a><br />
                <span class="source">Bob</span>
                <!-- displayed begin-->
            </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- ... -->
    </body>
</html>
```

In other words, you use javascript to change the `no-js` class to `js`, and then use CSS to hide `.js .read-more` but show `.no-js .read-more` (or whatever your hidden element's class name may be).

Hope this helps!

Comment: This is a good overall implementation idea.  I have several `<noscript>` blocks throughout the site, so this could help clean that up.